# Stored Procedure Parameters in DAL ASP.NET MVC w/out EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

EDIT: I forgot to add cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure.  If you forget this line MVC will act like you never passed the parameters.

I've got a table in my database that I wish to add a record using .NET MVC

DAL Code

```
public void AddCity(City city)
    {
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertCity", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                //these are the three properties of the City class
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityId", city.CityId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityName", city.CityName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryId", city.CountryId);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new City());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        //pass City object, or form?
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            City city = new City();
            city.CityId = Convert.ToInt32(form["CityId"]);
            city.CityName = form["CityName"];
            city.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(form["CountryId"]);
            var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
            dataAccess.AddCity(city);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
            var cityList = dataAccess.GetCities();
            return View(cityList);
        }
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","City")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>City</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CountryId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.CityId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CityId);
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityId)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

With the code I get an exception telling me that `@cityId parameter not provided`.  I'm aiming to take the posted values from the form that should constitute a `City` object and pass those to the DAL.  I have a couple of question:

1. Why isn't the model binder picking up the text box values as the parameters to my stored procedure?
2. In my DAL should I have the parameter as a `City` object, our three parameters for the three columns in the database table?

Comment: The way you are reading the values from the form means you are not using model binding.

Comment: @QuetiM.Porta wasn't quite sure if using FormCollection qualified for model binding or not.  Either way, for some reason, the values coming from the form text box are not getting into the stored procedure.  My view is strongly-typed to City

Answer (score 0):

Change the `FormCollection` to a strongly typed object like `City`

```
public ActionResult Create(City city)
        {
            var dataAccess = new DataAccessLayer();
            dataAccess.AddCity(city);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: I had that initially, but I still get the error that my stored procedure parameters are missing.

Comment: Is you view strongly typed like `@model city`? And when you put a break point inside your AddCity do you see which variable or properties are empty?

Comment: Yes, it's strongly typed to city.  The correct data is being passed in , but it fails on the cmd.ExectuteNonQuery line... The stored procedure works when I use it in SSSMS, though.

Comment: Got it.  It was because I didn't decalare the SqlCommand type as CommandType.StoredProcedure.